# Location leaking between vue-test-utils tests

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to create everything fresh for each tests, for example creating localVue in each test, however, the location seems to be leaking between unit tests. I am using vue-test-utils and jest with vue-router. The way I work around it is to explicitly navigate to '/' at the beginning of each test. Is it inevitable, or is there a way to isolate the tests from each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because you are running tests in an environment with `window` on the global, any changes to `window` or its properties affect future tests running in the same scope. The best approach is to reset any properties that you're altering in your source code before each test.